# CKEDITOR, calling the FullScreen Action outside of the CKEDITOR

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

Anyone with CKEDitor experience know if it is possible to use JavaScript to call with Full Screen function/action outside of the CKEDITOR?

thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think it is possible, have you tried the solution here:
http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=14319

It would probably be something like:

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.instances[instanceName];
editor.execCommand('maximize');
```

Comment: What is instanceName? when we can call editor.execCommand()?  I have problems running this code, see my answer for more direct implementation.

Comment: If you want to know if the editor is maximized use: `editor.getCommand('maximize').state === 1`.

Answer (score 3):

I tested @Magicgunnar but have problems to understand it, and to run (moment to trigg) it (!). This code if more self-explanatory and correct. Tested for 3.5.X:

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady',
   function( evt ) {
      var instanceName = 'textArea_id'; // the HTML id configured for editor
      var editor = CKEDITOR.instances[instanceName]; 
      editor.execCommand('maximize');
   }
 );
```

Comment: You shouldn't hardcode one editors id inside it's own event handling, just grab evt.editor and .execCommand() on it

Answer (score 2):

if using the jquery version of ckeditor the below code works perfectly

```
$(".fullscreen_link").live("click", function () {
        var editor = $('.my_ckeditor').ckeditorGet();
               editor.execCommand('maximize');
    });
```