# How can I open create a link inside CKeditor frame to open an input dialog on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I am trying to build a editor that will have some pre populated content and parts of the content need to be populated at runtime.
I want to provide an on click functionality in the editor content that will open a dialog box (a text input box/select dropdown/checkbox) and based on this update the content in the editor.

I have tried adding a new dialog box (something similar to : http://nightly.ckeditor.com/16-07-01-06-06/standard/samples/old/dialog/assets/my_dialog.js) but i am unable to open the dialog from the editor. 
I tried doing the following in my js:

```
var dialogObj = new CKEDITOR.dialog( editor, dialogName );
dialogObj.show();
```

but am getting an error: TypeError: f is undefined.

Comment: for opening the dialog box you can try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062110/ckeditor-calling-the-fullscreen-action-outside-of-the-ckeditor

Comment: Not what i am looking for. That question answers opening ckeditor in fullscreen. I am looking for opening a dialog box with my html on clicking an element present in the editable content of the editor.